# DDL contention on TempDB

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005, ddl, tempdb

I have a SQL Server 2005 Standard x64 that is experiencing issues with TempDB DDL contention for the past few months. The server will experiencing contention on wait resource 2:1:103 (the wait type being PAGELATCH_EX).

The issue appears to happen sporadically when the server is under decent load. I've been monitoring "Temp Tables for Destruction" rate and it can jump to 5,000+ during times when we have issues of PAGELATCH_EX on 2:1:103. From what I've read this counter should be 0 the majority of the time, but ours seems to stay anywhere from 300-1100 the majority of the time. The counter only goes to 0 when there is very few users on the system.

How can I narrow down what is causing the DDL contention on tempdb without having to look for a needle in a hay stack?

Comment: What is `SELECT @@VERSION;`? As per my answer my first suggestion will be to make sure you are on SP4 and the most recent cumulative update.

Comment: It is SP4 (9.00.5000)

Answer (score 14):

I've seen this very issue and the hotfix that was ultimately released to fix it was actually a direct result of my case with Microsoft CSS. There is no public KB article for the fix. Please make sure you've applied [Service Pack 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b953e84f-9307-405e-bceb-47bd345baece) and the most recent cumulative update to SQL Server (at the time of writing, that's [Cumulative Update #3 (9.00.5259)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2507769)).

Until the hotfix was released, Microsoft's suggestion was to simply stop creating #temp tables (much like [KB #916086](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916086)). Since this would have meant a substantial re-write of dozens and dozens of reporting procedures, the workaround in my case (regardless of trace flags or temp file layout) was to restart our cluster every other weekend. Yuck.

In order to track down tempdb usage, there are several scripts around that can help, e.g. see Adam Machanic's [sp_whoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com), specifically:

- [sp_whoisactive: Analyzing Tempdb Contention](http://whoisactive.com/docs/21_tempdb/)
- [How to identify which query is filling up the tempdb transaction log?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/19870/1186)

And also this script (and ones in the comments) from @SQLSoldier:

- [Breaking Down TempDB Contention](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/robert_davis/archive/2010/03/05/Breaking-Down-TempDB-Contention.aspx)

I would make sure all your cursors are using `LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY` (see [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options) and [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options-2)), and see if there are any known expensive queries that make extensive use of #temp tables / @table variables, CTEs, or may contain unnecessary sorts or lead to hash joins... all of which can contribute to the problem (I doubt you'll find one golden cause). The easiest sweeping fix as a "bang-for-your-buck" starting point will be to use proper and inexpensive cursor options instead of the defaults.

In the meantime I would (a) install CU#3 and (b) call PSS. Tell them you are after a very specific fix that has already been confirmed as a bug and released to other users as a private hotfix: ***"VSTS #109112 - Temp table deferred drop doesn't scale for certain workloads."*** You may have to pay the case fee initially but, since it is a bug, the charge should be refunded.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64619/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron-bertrand-ddl-contention-on-tempdb).

Answer (score 5):

I presume that you've already split out your TempDB data-files to try to alleviate contention (via pre-production first obviously). If you're braver, consider the trace flag that Paul Randal authoratively refers to:
http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-(1230)-tempdb-should-always-have-one-data-file-per-processor-core.aspx

In terms of what is causing the pain, you need to do some investigative work:

- has this just started to occur? what has changed?
- is the server under memory pressure, so sorts have to be done in TempDB?
- are there any DBA processes like CheckDB, or online re-indexing, running?
- are more exotic isolation levels used, or service broker? have a look at sys.databases

There's a nice query at the bottom of this Microsoft TempDB document to try to work out what is using tempdb:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc966545.aspx

Comment: The associated info on TF1118 is probably more important I reckon

Comment: @gbn 
It started a few months ago and there were no server changes. We have tried TF1118 with no luck as that doesn't really help with the issue we are having (serialized access to that system meta data table creating locks on 2:1:103). Stemming from a ton of temp tables needing to be destroyed. 

No DBA task are running during this time. No service broker and no exotic isolation levels.

Comment: No server changes, but were there any application code changes? Is memory ok - page life expectancy, query run times etc?

Comment: I would give the multiple TempDB files a try - via pre-prod first to ensure there's nothing unexpected. It's an innocuous change which does work.

Incidentally, have you checked your disc IO latencies, especially for TempDB?

Comment: I've tested all checked all that out and IO latency is not an issue. TempDB has been configured in several different multiple file configuration with no relief. It is a 24-core system so we have been running the 8 tempdev files, but have tried different configurations all the way to 24 files. Memory is okay, page life expectancy is also good. Query run times are up and down, but nothing crazy, or new.

Comment: @DavidGeorge - FYI: ["The SQL CAT team has also found that in 2005 and 2008, there's usually no gain from having more than 8 tempdb data files, even for systems with larger numbers of processor cores."](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Misconceptions-around-TF-1118.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You probably need trace flag 1118

See [Paul Randal's myths about tempdb](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-%281230%29-tempdb-should-always-have-one-data-file-per-processor-core.aspx) first, and his [TF 1118 article too](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Misconceptions-around-TF-1118.aspx)

The TF is described here in [KB 328551](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328551)

I have no direct experience of this but it sounds like what I've read

Comment: unfortunately TF1118 has provided no help

Answer (score 4):

If you are still looking to track this down, I recently had a similarly strange performance issue with synchronous table drops. If you have large numbers of databases (> 100 or so) on a sql instance running SQL 2005 and you have lots of temp table create and drop statements you can get slow temp table drops. Checking row count returned from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats can rule this out pretty much right away as the culprit.

KB article describes the problem. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2003031

> Query performance decreases when sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats has large
>   number of rows
>
> Consider the following scenario:
>
> In Microsoft SQL Server 2005, you frequently perform DDL operation
>   that involve dropping and recreation of lot of tables (especially
>   temporary tables in tempdb database). You have a large number of
>   entries (100,000 or more) in the sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats dynamic
>   management view (DMV).

Taken from my accepted answer to this question. There's some more detail there as well.
[Slow temp table drops in sql 2005](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7753/slow-temp-table-drops-in-sql-2005)