# What does "ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER" do? Is there anything to worry about?

Tags: sql-server

I'm having an issue with sql broker service. Is there a reason to worry about setting a new sql broker service? I'm really worried about doing this, but I'm kind of at my wits end since I know it will clear out the message queue to send out, but is this the only thing I need to worry about? Is there anything else that I should be looking for or that has to be done when I do run this statement?

Comment: You're asking about a possible fix, but what is your actual root problem?

Comment: @ThomasStringer I think this is: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56703/issues-with-tempdb-mdf-file-ever-increasing

Comment: I'm more concerned with the fact that if I set a new broker, what I have to worry about doing to make sure my instance of service broker is back to how I just had it. Is there a way to batch delete messages out of the sys.conversation_endpoints table? I know about running an infinite while loop, just wondering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only if your database participates in distributed conversations. `NEW_BROKER` changes your `service_broker_id`. If you created any route with service name *and* service instance then it will become invalid as the route service instance value no longer reflect the destination `service_broker_guid`. It goes w/o saying that doing NEW_BROKER on a database that does have running conversations that span isntances (or even DBs in the same conversation), these conversations will have one half 'nuked' and the other half will be left stranded, unable to make any progress (will have to be cleaned up with END ... WITH CLEANUP or the other database will also have to be NEW_BROKER-ed).

Be aware that NEW_BROKER affects hidden conversations like the ones created by Event Notifications.

If everything you have is local, in the same db, then you have basically nothing to worry about.

Comment: thanks for the help remus, all of the service broker messages, queues, etc...are in the same db, but we have messages coming from other servers/db's going to service broker and then going to an instance of mongodb, which in turn sends back an id to indicate the message was received...going by the structure that was put around our instance of service broker, i'd have to test in another environment to truly gauge the effects it'll have. Didn't know that setting a new broker actually affected event notifications...something to chew on. Thanks for your help again remus