# How do I completely reset ServiceBroker including all messages, queues, triggers, etc?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have a database where I have a ServiceBroker up and running. For unknown reasons we have experienced a lot of problems with missing conversation handlers;

I.e.

```
The conversation handle "D33EC01C-CEA9-E811-95C5-00155D009F03" is not found.
```

It is my belief that this has happened when DB has been restarted while conversations have been "open" if that makes any sense.

What I wish to do now is to "reset" the ServiceBroker, remove all conversations, messages, triggers(!) etc.

Unfortunately I haven´t seen any documentation on how to achieve this.

Ideas?

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE db SET NEW_BROKER;` but [read this first](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56938/1186).

Comment: No, `ALTER DATABASE db SET NEW_BROKER;` will not remove the triggers, queues etc. ONLY messages.

Comment: I don't know of any way to remove triggers. I don't even know what triggers are in the context of service broker. For the queues you could certainly drop them and re-create them...

Answer (score -1):

Its cause due to multi-trigger on the table which created by service broker.

[image]

Delete all trigger and start broker services or then try.