# Secondary Tempdb filling up on AG Setup

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, tempdb

I'm currently facing this problem in one of my Production environments.

I have an AG with around 130 DBs with readable secondaries enabled. However, there are not routing lists defined and applications are not using it. From time to time, tempdb on my secondary fills up completely.

Doing an evaluation what I was able to get was.

tempdb size: 255GB

```
free pages  free space in MB
27571456    215402.000000

version store pages used    version store space in MB
5130624                      40083.000000
```

To see what is using row versioning I am using the following query.

```
select 
    hostname,
    elapsed_time_seconds,
    session_id, 
    is_snapshot, 
    blocked, 
    lastwaittype, 
    cpu, 
    physical_io,  
    open_tran, cmd,
    DB_NAME(b.dbid)
from 
    sys.dm_tran_active_snapshot_database_transactions a
join master..sysprocesses b
    on a.session_id=b.spid 
order by 
    a.elapsed_time_seconds desc
```

[image]

From this point I am stuck with ideas on where to look the problem. I also didn't want to restart the secondary as this is not going to fix the issue.

Any ideas that someone could share with me?

Regards,
Marcos Freccia

Comment: Check out [this answer from Aaron](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19871/95107) to see what is actually taking up the allocations. Maybe someone is running a query against the RoR via a report or custom script.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same issue. We have an Availability group where the secondary was having TempDB blow up and the primary was fine.

I created three tables and ran three stored procedures every 1-5 minutes on the secondary node. They are pretty light loads, obviously you should test them beforehand.

Here are the tables:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TempDBDataGrowth]    Script Date: 4/12/2018 1:13:35 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempDBDataGrowth](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStart] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [database_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Size] [decimal](38, 2) NULL,
    [UsedSpace] [decimal](38, 2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TempDBDataGrowth]    Script Date: 4/12/2018 1:13:35 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempDBDataGrowth](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStart] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [database_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Size] [decimal](38, 2) NULL,
    [UsedSpace] [decimal](38, 2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[WhoIsActive]    Script Date: 4/12/2018 1:15:12 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WhoIsActive](
    [dd hh:mm:ss.mss] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [dd hh:mm:ss.mss (avg)] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [session_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [sql_text] [xml] NULL,
    [sql_command] [xml] NULL,
    [login_name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [wait_info] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [tran_log_writes] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [CPU] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [CPU_delta] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [tempdb_allocations] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [tempdb_current] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [tempdb_allocations_delta] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [tempdb_current_delta] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [blocking_session_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [blocked_session_count] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [reads] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [reads_delta] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [writes] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [writes_delta] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [physical_reads] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [physical_reads_delta] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [query_plan] [xml] NULL,
    [locks] [xml] NULL,
    [used_memory] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [used_memory_delta] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [status] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [tran_start_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [open_tran_count] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [percent_complete] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [host_name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [database_name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [program_name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [additional_info] [xml] NULL,
    [start_time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [login_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [request_id] [int] NULL,
    [collection_time] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Here are the three scripts I'm using to collect information: (For sp_whoisactive, you will need to download that procedure online.)

http://whoisactive.com/

```
USE tempdb
insert into master.dbo.TempDBDataGrowth
(TimeStart, name, database_id, size,UsedSpace)
   SELECT   
        getdate() as timestart,
         SD.name,
         MF.database_id,
         SUM( CONVERT(decimal(10,2),(DF.size/128.0)) ) as Size,  
         SUM( CONVERT(decimal(10,2), (CAST(FILEPROPERTY(DF.name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128.0 ) ) ) AS UsedSpace
   FROM sys.master_files MF JOIN sys.databases SD
      ON SD.database_id = MF.database_id 
   JOIN sys.database_files DF
      ON DF.physical_name collate DATABASE_DEFAULT = MF.physical_name collate DATABASE_DEFAULT
   WHERE MF.type = 0 
   GROUP BY SD.name, MF.database_id;

insert into master.dbo.TempDBDataUsage
(
TimeStart, QueryExecutionContextDBID, QueryExecContextDBNAME, ModuleObjectId, 
Query_Text, session_id, request_id, exec_context_id, OutStanding_user_objects_page_counts, 
OutStanding_internal_objects_page_counts, start_time, command, open_transaction_count, 
percent_complete, estimated_completion_time, cpu_time, total_elapsed_time, reads, 
writes, logical_reads, granted_query_memory, HOST_NAME, login_name, program_name
)
   SELECT
   getdate() as Timestart,
st.dbid AS QueryExecutionContextDBID,
DB_NAME(st.dbid) AS QueryExecContextDBNAME,
st.objectid AS ModuleObjectId,
SUBSTRING(st.TEXT,
dmv_er.statement_start_offset/2 + 1,
(CASE WHEN dmv_er.statement_end_offset = -1
THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),st.TEXT)) * 2
ELSE dmv_er.statement_end_offset
END - dmv_er.statement_start_offset)/2) AS Query_Text,
dmv_tsu.session_id ,
dmv_tsu.request_id,
dmv_tsu.exec_context_id,
(dmv_tsu.user_objects_alloc_page_count - dmv_tsu.user_objects_dealloc_page_count) AS OutStanding_user_objects_page_counts,
(dmv_tsu.internal_objects_alloc_page_count - dmv_tsu.internal_objects_dealloc_page_count) AS OutStanding_internal_objects_page_counts,
dmv_er.start_time,
dmv_er.command,
dmv_er.open_transaction_count,
dmv_er.percent_complete,
dmv_er.estimated_completion_time,
dmv_er.cpu_time,
dmv_er.total_elapsed_time,
dmv_er.reads,dmv_er.writes,
dmv_er.logical_reads,
dmv_er.granted_query_memory,
dmv_es.HOST_NAME,
dmv_es.login_name,
dmv_es.program_name
FROM sys.dm_db_task_space_usage dmv_tsu
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests dmv_er
ON (dmv_tsu.session_id = dmv_er.session_id AND dmv_tsu.request_id = dmv_er.request_id)
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions dmv_es
ON (dmv_tsu.session_id = dmv_es.session_id)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dmv_er.sql_handle) st
WHERE (dmv_tsu.internal_objects_alloc_page_count + dmv_tsu.user_objects_alloc_page_count) > 0
ORDER BY (dmv_tsu.user_objects_alloc_page_count - dmv_tsu.user_objects_dealloc_page_count) + (dmv_tsu.internal_objects_alloc_page_count - dmv_tsu.internal_objects_dealloc_page_count) DESC;

USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @schema varchar(max)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_WhoIsActive]
        @get_full_inner_text = 1,
        @get_plans = 1,
        @get_outer_command = 1,
        @get_transaction_info = 1,
        @get_task_info = 1,
        @get_locks = 1,
        @get_avg_time = 1,
        @get_additional_info = 1,
        @find_block_leaders = 1,
        @delta_interval = 1,
                @destination_table = 'WhoIsActive',
        @schema = @schema OUTPUT



SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

This takes 1-2 seconds to run in my environment, I scheduled it for every 5 minutes. You should adjust as necessary, I left this as a job running for a week at 5 minute intervals and then I looked at the DB growth portions to see when my TempDB was filling. Then I looked at sp_whoisactive to see what query was running at that time.

Here are some queries I ran afterwards to help me find my culprits:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM [master].[dbo].[TempDBDataGrowth]
  order by UsedSpace desc

SELECT TOP 1000  *
  FROM [master].[dbo].[TempDBDataUsage]
  order by writes desc

SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM [master].[dbo].[WhoIsActive]
  order by tempdb_allocations desc
```