# TempDB log file bloated suddenly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, tempdb

I am trying to understand what could be the possible reason which would have caused tempdb ldf file grow full and went out of space on the drive it resides.

Compared the pattern for last month and today was the unusual behaviour of tempdb.

From third party tools i have all the SQl that were running in that 8 hour window but what exactly is the correct way to find the culprit process?

Comment: Check out Aarons answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/how-to-identify-which-query-is-filling-up-the-tempdb-transaction-log

Comment: But those are the case when problem is still there. As a quick fix an old tran was killed on urgent fly as drive was full and created an outage. How can i go to  look in past?